# A question on continued J-fraction

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, generating-functions, continued-fractions, hankel-matrices

Consider the following two continued fractions $A$ and $B$:

$$\frac{\alpha_0}{1+a_0x-\frac{b_1x^2}{1+a_1x-\frac{b_2x^2}{1+a_2x-\cdots}}}$$
$$\frac{\beta_0}{1+c_0x-\frac{d_1x}{1+c_1x-\frac{d_2x}{1+c_2x-\cdots}}}$$

where $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i$ and $\alpha_0,\beta_0$ are real numbers. 
The first fraction $A$ is called J-fraction. Can I rewrite the second fraction $B$ in the form of J-fraction $A$?
Any suggestions, please?

Comment: The second fraction is called a T-fraction.

Comment: J-fraction is associated with a Hankel deteminant. Is T-fraction also associated with a Hankel determinant?

Comment: I don't know much about them, but you can look them up. They're also called Thron-type continued fractions. Two references are https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-54/issue-2/Some-properties-of-continued-fractions-1--d_0-z-/bams/1183511691.full and https://www.jstor.org/stable/44237585 .

Comment: thanks, can u share any link for the relation between the continued fractions and determinants?

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902004 and https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503507.

Comment: thanks for this.

Comment: You said that $$\frac{\beta_0}{1+c_0x-\frac{d_1x}{1+c_1x-\frac{d_2x}{1+c_2x-\cdots}}}$$ is called a T-fraction. Did you mean a Test-fraction?

Comment: Please take a look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407323/a-continued-j-fraction-for-a-n-frac1n2

Comment: No, T stands for Thron, who studied this continued fractions in https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-54/issue-2/Some-properties-of-continued-fractions-1--d_0-z-/bams/1183511691.full