# A continued J fraction for $a_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, generating-functions, continued-fractions, hankel-matrices

The following is called a J continued fraction:

$$\cfrac{\alpha_0}{1+a_0x-\cfrac{b_1x^2}{1+a_1x-\cfrac{b_2x^2}{1+a_2x-\cdots}}}$$

where the constants are real numbers. Let $\alpha_n= \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ for $n\geq 0$. I want to write the J-fraction expansion of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_nx^n.$ Is there any algorithm for this? If not, what should be a good start?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it.

Comment: I got confused between $a_n$ and $\alpha_n$, now I've edited it.

Comment: how can we find the first few coefficients of the power series expansion of above J-fraction in terms of $\alpha_0, a_i,b_i$?

Comment: I am just using `Series` in Mathematica.

Comment: Not that it clarifies anything, but the first few numbers are $a_0=-\frac14$, $b_1=\frac7{144}$, $a_1=-\frac{13}{28}$, $b_2=\frac{647}{11025}$, $a_2=-\frac{8795}{18116}$, ...

Comment: How r u doing this is Mathematica? Can you please share a screenshot?

Comment: See the answer - it is much more concise and efficient than what I am doing

Answer (score 4):

Sagemath can do that too

```
  sage: x = PowerSeriesRing(QQ,'x').gen()
  sage: f = sum(x**n/(n+1)**2 for n in range(20)).O(20)
  sage: f.jacobi_continued_fraction()
  ((-1/4, -7/144),
   (-13/28, -647/11025),
   (-8795/18116, -71180289/1172105200),
  etc
```